# Exported files are silent. Pro Tools First

Tags: pro-tools, freeware, windows-10

I have a multi track session which has all the tracks recorded using smartphone and then imported the .wav files from phone to DAW. I have mixed and my project is ready to export. For the life of me, the exported files are silent. Here are the things I tried:

1. Unchecked `Offline` option at the bottom. This way, I have to listen to the whole audio track as it records into the exported file. It's still silent.
2. Tried different bit rates and bit depth. No luck
3. The exported silent file when re imported to Pro Tools First works fine. I re exported this single stereo track again, but the resulting file is silent again.

All the online help directs me to File > Bounce > To Disk. I use Windows 10 and free copy of Pro Tools First 2018.4.0 and I just have `Import` & `Export` but no `Bounce` option in me `File` menu.

[image]

How do I export to an mp3 or wav audo file?

My Mix Panel:
[image]